# Increase timeout for RunAsync

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am creating a number of Service Bus Clients in the RunAsync method on a statefull service.

The method takes longer than the 4 seconds that is allowed when running in the development environment and the application fail to start.

It fails because of what appears to be latency between my dev machine and Azure.

I am in Thailand. Azure is in South Central US.

Can that 4000 millisecond timeout be increased locally on my dev box?

The error i get is:

```
{ 
{

  "Message": "RunAsync has been cancelled for a stateful service replica. The cancellation will be considered 'slow' if RunAsync does not halt execution within 4000 milliseconds.        
  "Level": "Informational",
  "Keywords": "0x0000F00000000000",
  "EventName": "StatefulRunAsyncCancellation",
  "Payload": {
[...]
"slowCancellationTimeMillis": 4000.0
```

}
   }

Comment: It is a slow warning i am getting. I have edited my post with more details. Of course, this very moment the application stated fine ... without any code changes.

Comment: I am getting the error when the instance becomes starts up first time and becomes primary first time.

Comment: It is hard to ignore, as it prevents the cluster to start but it is working now :-) I will spin up a dev environment in South Central US instead and deal with it that way if the problem comes back. Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not that `RunAsync` takes too long to run, it's that it takes too long to *cancel*.

Service Fabric has a default (hard-coded) timeout 4 seconds for *reporting* "slow" cancellations. That just means that after that time it will produce a health event (which may be important during upgrades as it affects the health status of the entire application).

The real problem is the implementation of `RunAsync`. When you remove a service or upgrade one, Service Fabric will wait (potentially forever) for it to shut down gracefully. Your code should respect the `CancellationToken` passed to the `RunAsync` method. For example, if you have multiple IO operations, call `cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` after each one (whenever possible) and pass it to any method that accepts it as a parameter.

Comment: Thank you for info. I will review that part of the code.

Comment: @Eli is there any way to have Service Fabric just kill my service? It does its work safely and 'idempotently', so it can be killed anytime without sorrow (or health events)